# I am attempting to select multiple files, create worksheets based on file name and read that data into a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have figured out how to select multiple files using `msoFileDialogOpen` property. Now I have multiple file paths that I have selected, I would like to create new worksheets based on the names of the files (names are found at the end of the file path after "\"). I then would like to make sure no duplicate worksheets are created for the same file. Also, would like to read in data from said file, parse it and output to corresponding worksheet.

I have attempted to create the new worksheets but have not attempted to read, parse and output the data from txt file to worksheet.

```vb
Sub readTxtFile()
    Dim fPath As Long

    ' Open the file browser
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show
    End With

    Dim sheetName
    For fPath = 1 To FileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        sheetName = Right(fPath, 11)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)) = sheetName

        'insert code to read in data and output to excel
    Next FilePath
End Sub
```

If I have a text file named ReadMe1.txt, ReadMe2.txt, and ReadMe3.txt, I would like to select all of these text files from my computer (as file paths), and then name a worksheet "ReadMe1" for example. If I were to click my macro button again, I shouldn't be able to create worksheet "ReadMe1" if it still exists. Then read the data from the txt file and output it to the new worksheet.

Comment: Add another For...Next loop that compares the new sheet name to all of the current sheet names. Is that enough info to help?

Comment: "read in data from said file, parse it and output to corresponding worksheet" - can you open the file directly from Excel?  What kind of "parsing" are you talking about here?

Comment: the txt files have 3 columns (one header column) and a random amount of rows.  I would like to read the data from the txt file and parse(separate) into cells in a worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add the sheets based on the selected files.  You'll need to say more about the format of the files to be imported.

```
Sub readTxtFile()
    Dim i As Long, fso As Object, filePath As String, sheetName As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, fd As FileDialog


    ' Open the file browser
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")


    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count

        filePath = fd.SelectedItems(i)
        sheetName = fso.getbasename(filePath)

        'see if the sheet already exists
        Set sht = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if not found
        Set sht = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors

        If sht Is Nothing Then
            'create the new sheet and name it
            Set sht = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
            sht.Name = sheetName

            'read in the source file here

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked. Would you mind explaining the scripting line as well as the getbasename property

Comment: The filesystem object is from the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library, and you can spin up an object of that type using `CreateObject`.  It has a bunch of methods for working with files and folders: https://www.thevbprogrammer.com/ch06/06-09-fso.htm   Note - it's not available on the Mac platform...